# Unit Testing Vimscript built-ins: possible to override/mock or inject substitutes?

Tags: vimscript, unit-testing

I found a bug in the CoC plugin, and I was going to fix the bug, but first I wanted to write some documentation/learning tests as well as a regression test. The question was how: unit testing does not seem to be that much used, apart from the existence of the [Vader.vim project](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim).

The piece of code I would like to test does some tests for the existence of some patches in the version of the Vim running (i.e. `has('nvim-0.4.0')`), but in order to test that in a manner that does not rely on my own version of Vim, I would need to control the `has` function. Is it possible to override/mock that function (or any other built-in for that matter)? [The author of Vader thinks the answer is no](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim/issues/58).

I could redo this function to do DI of some sorts:

```
let Local_has = has
if exists("*Testing_has"):
    Local_has = Testing_has
endif
  
if Local_has('nvim-0.4.0'):
  do_something
endif
```

[In Learn VimScript the hard way they mention storing function references](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/39.html#functions-as-variables), and this seems to be a good beginning:

```
let MyHas = function("has")
let YourHas = MyHas

echo has('nvim-0.4.3') " => 1
echo MyHas('nvim-0.4.3') " => 1
echo YourHas('nvim-0.4.3') " => 1
```

The question remains on how to inject the testing version. Just write a test.vim that has created the overrides that then sources the main script?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to mock Vimscript/VimL functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363366/is-there-a-way-to-mock-vimscript-viml-functions)

Comment: Not applicable to builtin functions though.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that even if it were possible, it's not a good practice to mock `has(` in this way.  Instead, you should test directly against the versions of vim which you are trying to support.  Many vim plugins do have CI pipelines which test the most latest version of vim, vim 8.0, vim 7.4, various neovim versions, etc.  Automated testing frameworks in github and gitlab today makes this very easy.  Similarly, you can use different vim builds and configurations with and without various features.

The reason I advise this is vim often changes in subtle ways that aren't just "add a feature."  Often when a feature, function, command, etc, is added other adjacent things are fixed and altered.  It's better to test against a real deployment.

In addition, if you need to test the "exceptional" branch of the `has(` code, you're better off directly testing the components that you need to use.  If the contents of the `if has(` is really long and complicated, well, generally, it's a bit nicer to refactor the code to allow true "unit" testing than to start mocking things which might break in the next code release.

Comment: Thanks for the good overview. I agree that those are good general rules. In this case, it was an existing plugin with no tests, and I wanted to find a way to test the logic locally by controlling the return values of `has(val)` _without substantially refactoring the original code when doing so_, as I don't think large changes would have been accepted. In the end, I created [a little POC](https://github.com/fatso83/coc.nvim/commit/6d7d0d3) that essentially pre-processed the plugin source code and and replaced calls to built-ins. Not a thing of beauty, but a fun exercise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible either.

I'd say you may found a solution depending on how the call to `has()`  is used.
Sometimes you will be able to overwrite the direct consequence of a call to `has()`  (like changing/removing a function/a command... that depends on `has()`  result), other times it wouldn't be possible.

In all cases, if the plugin you want to mock directly uses a builtin function, it's not possible to overwrite this function. At best, you could copy the whole plugin elsewhere, substitute all calls to `has()` by calls to `your#mock#has()`, and update the runtime path to use this manually *mocked fork*.

PS: there exist quite few unit testing frameworks for Vim. I'm even maintaining [one](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-UT).

Comment: I actually wrote a POC stubbing framework for this, just for the fun of it. Was an interesting exercise :) https://github.com/fatso83/coc.nvim/commit/6d7d0d3461dad2bc03a757ad4654e94d07b0f97a#diff-65372dd7a2f98d044351ab1b251062e41cdcbf6ae3386e3904548bc397a479faR9-R20